# HelpVerbOption is not working - Command Line Parser C#

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

I have a class:

```
class Options
{
    // Remainder omitted (verb1, verb2, verb3)
    [HelpVerbOption]
    public string GetUsage(string verb)
    {
        return HelpText.AutoBuild(this, verb);
    }
}
```

The [docs](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/wiki/Verb-Commands) say:

> [...] The parser will pass null to master class GetUsage(string) also if
>   the user requested the help index with:
>
> $ git help
>
> or the verb command if the user requested explicitly
>   instructions on how to use a particular verb:
>
> $ git help commit
>
> [...]

Then, I typed `MyApp.exe help verb1`, but I could see only the base help (that looked like I typed the wrong verb, or `help` verb, or something). Rather, I expect it to show the help message related to specified verb. Why isn't it working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works using the mentioned approach, but only if I call my app without the `--help`-option (for instance `MyApp batch`). When I use `MyApp --help batch` the behaviour is as described by you.

However we can´t seem to get the same to work for the `help`-option.

EDIT: I managed to get this working by modifying the code of `Commandline.Parser.cs` with the following:

```
private bool TryParseHelpVerb(string[] args, object options, Pair<MethodInfo, HelpVerbOptionAttribute> helpInfo, OptionMap optionMap)
{
    var helpWriter = _settings.HelpWriter;
    if (helpInfo != null && helpWriter != null)
    {
        if (string.Compare(args[0], helpInfo.Right.LongName, GetStringComparison(_settings)) == 0)
        {
            // User explicitly requested help
            var verb = args.FirstOrDefault(); // <----- change this to args[1];
            if (verb != null)
            {
                var verbOption = optionMap[verb];
                if (verbOption != null)
                {
                    if (verbOption.GetValue(options) == null)
                    {
                        // We need to create an instance also to render help
                        verbOption.CreateInstance(options);
                    }
                }
            }
            DisplayHelpVerbText(options, helpInfo, verb);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The problem appears at the line

```
var verb = args.FirstOrDefault();
```

As the very first argument (`args[0]`) is interpreteted as the verb or better the **action** (as described in the docs) `verb` will allways be `help` here. So we replace this by `args[1]` which contains the *actual* verb, for example `commit`.

EDIT2: To make this work for `--help` also we should also trim the first arg (`args[0]`) from the `-`-character

```
if (string.Compare(args[0].Trim('-'), helpInfo.Right.LongName, GetStringComparison(_settings)) == 0)
```

Comment: Can you help me to do this changes in my project?
I using `CommanLine` as a library. So i can't change it source code. Then i clone repo from git and try to find the `TryParseHelpVerb` function or `DisplayHelpVerbText` but can't find anything. What i need to do?

Comment: Download the source-code, change it appropriately and build it as a lib.

Comment: For everyone i should notice: you need to change and compile "stable" branch. When it successfully compiled, you need to replace that libs in "bin\debug" folder and in "packages\CommandLineParser\lib\net45" folder. Good luck!